# UWP application not going to suspend state

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

In my UWP application I am using app service as in process background task to communicate with the win32 application to get the information.My application is not even going to suspend state. It always stays in the running state.But when i kill my win32 application it is going to suspend state.

For making application to suspend state followed steps in [How to make UWP app to suspend and resume state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561851/how-to-make-uwp-app-to-suspend-and-resume-state)

I also tried with the Samples provided by microsoft in git https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample/cs

In this Application also I can able to see the Similar behaviour.

Is there any way to make the appplication to suspend state without killing win32 application?

Comment: Your app keeps running as long as the app service has an active client. Close the service connection in the win32 app to allow UWP app to suspend.

Comment: if i close the connection, when my app comes from suspend state to resume state I need that service connection to communicate again with win32 application.But it is not possible

Comment: To separate things, you could host the app service out-of-proc. This way your UWP can suspend and the app service can keep open.